# Array findIndex() function - Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement addtoCart function in Angular2.
I am using typescript class to represent a LineItem which is to represent product along with quantity and total price ( quantity * product price).

```
export interface Product {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  price?: number;
}
```

Line items:

```
export class LineItem {
  product: Product;
  quantity: number;
  totalPrice: number;
}
```

Array of Line items:

```
lineItems: LineItem[];
```

In add to cart function, I want to check if the item is already added, if so just find the line item corresponding the product and update that specific line item.

Method I am choosing is: 
- find the index.
- if it is >-1 then add the new line item.
- else edit the line item.

Issue is: When I am trying to find the index it shows this error

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

code is :

```
  addProductToCart(product: any, quantity: number) {
    const lineItem: LineItem = Object.assign({}, product);
    lineItem.quantity = quantity;
    lineItem.totalPrice = product.price * quantity;
    const index = this.lineItems.findIndex( (item) => {
       return item.product.id === product.id
    });
    if(index > -1) {
      // edit the current item .
      this.lineItems[index].quantity = quantity;
      this.lineItems[index].totalPrice = quantity * product.price;

    }else {
      this.lineItems.push(lineItem);
    }
  }
```

no error on first call, second call throws error.
this is the problem line:

```
  const index = this.lineItems.findIndex( (item) => {
       return item.product.id === product.id
    });
```

item.product.id throws : Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

is it something with typescript class or interface or any logical error.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `product.id` that's throwing? That's on the same line. Have you logged the values of `item`, `item.product` and `product` to see what's there? That would seem to be the first thing to try when debugging. We don't have any of your data, so it's pretty hard to tell.

Comment: Log your lineItems in console and see what you get there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const lineItem: LineItem = Object.assign({}, product);
```

This line result  as a plain object :

```
lineItem = {ProductID: 1, ProductName: "Chai", UnitPrice: 18, quantity: 2}
```

So there is no item.product.id object chain its simple plain object

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/5UCWQSsNMBHqsNndUmTj?p=preview)

Comment: lineItem is type of `LineItem`, not `Product`. And product is not an array, so this is basically wrong: `this.lineItems.product.push(lineItem);`